# System.Data.SQLite slow execution of large script

Tags: .net, sqlite, ado.net, system.data.sqlite, sqlitestudio

I'm trying to run an SQL file from my .NET application but the run time is extremely slow. I'm not sure how to optimize it to run faster. I know that the script works because when I run it in the SQLite shell application it executes in less than 1 second. In my .NET application it just hangs on `sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`.

Here's an excerpt from the script.sql file:

```
--
-- File generated with SQLiteStudio v3.1.1 on Thu Feb 15 11:33:12 2018
--
-- Text encoding used: System
--
PRAGMA foreign_keys = off;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

-- Table: Document_Type
CREATE TABLE [Document_Type] (
    [Id]    integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
    [Type]  nvarchar(50) NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE

);
INSERT INTO Document_Type (Id, Type) VALUES (1, '.docx');
INSERT INTO Document_Type (Id, Type) VALUES (2, '.xlsm');
INSERT INTO Document_Type (Id, Type) VALUES (3, '.jpeg');

-- Table: Learn_More
CREATE TABLE [Learn_More] (
    [item_ID]   integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
    [field_name]    nvarchar(100) COLLATE NOCASE,
    [description]   text(1073741823) COLLATE NOCASE,
    [location]  char(10) COLLATE NOCASE

);
INSERT INTO Learn_More (item_ID, field_name, description, location) VALUES (1, 'System Name', 'Full descriptive name of the system.*      Example: Agency Billing System ', 'SSP1      ');
.
.
.
.
.
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
PRAGMA foreign_keys = on;
```

The script.sql file is 35,831 lines. I plan on cleaning up the column types  after I can get it to run in .NET.

My .NET code:

```
Dim baseDir As String = Application.UserAppDataPath()
Dim db3Path As String = baseDir + "\Schema Scripts\ProgrammaticallyGenerateDatabase\Test.db3"
Dim sqlPath As String = baseDir + "\Schema Scripts\script.sql"

SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(db3Path)

Dim sqlite_conn = New SQLiteConnection("Data Source= " & db3Path)
Using sqlite_conn
    sqlite_conn.Open()
    Dim sqlite_cmd = sqlite_conn.CreateCommand()
    'Dim sqlite_tran = sqlite_conn.BeginTransaction()

    'Using sqlite_tran

        Using sqlite_cmd
            Try
                sqlite_cmd.CommandText = File.ReadAllText(sqlPath)
                sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Type FROM Document_Type"

                Dim sqlite_datareader = sqlite_cmd.ExecuteReader()
                While (sqlite_datareader.Read())
                    Dim textReader As String = sqlite_datareader.GetString(0)

                    Console.WriteLine(textReader)
                End While
            Catch ex As Exception
                'End Using
                'sqlite_tran.Commit()
            End Try
        End Using
    sqlite_conn.Close()
End Using
```

I've tried using `File.OpenText(sqlPath).ReadToEnd()` but had the same performance issue.

Any ideas on how to speed this up? Just to reiterate, the same file runs in less than 1 second in the SQLite shell program using the `.read script.sql` command.

EDIT:

This is a win app. The code is running on a background thread and takes 483801 milliseconds to complete.

I came up with a solution that works for my case. The query now runs in ~700-900ms. I'm just bundling the sqlite3.exe with my application and calling it with the command line.

Here's the code:

```
Private Sub SQLiteButtonPress()
        Dim baseDir As String = Application.UserAppDataPath() + "\Schema Scripts"
        Dim db3Path As String = baseDir + "\ProgrammaticallyGenerateDatabase\Test.db3"
        Dim sqlPath As String = baseDir + "\Baseline Schema.sql"

        Dim watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew()
        Console.WriteLine("Starting Stopwatch")

        Try
            Dim proc As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo()
            proc.Arguments = "/c sqlite3.exe """ + db3Path + """ < """ + sqlPath + """"
            proc.FileName = "cmd.exe"
            proc.UseShellExecute = False
            proc.CreateNoWindow = True

            Dim p As New Process()
            p.StartInfo = proc
            p.Start()
            p.WaitForExit()

            Dim sqlite_conn = New SQLiteConnection("Data Source= " & db3Path)
            Using sqlite_conn
                sqlite_conn.Open()
                Dim sqlite_cmd = sqlite_conn.CreateCommand()

                Using sqlite_cmd
                        sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Type FROM Document_Type"

                        Dim sqlite_datareader = sqlite_cmd.ExecuteReader()
                        While (sqlite_datareader.Read())
                            Dim textReader As String = sqlite_datareader.GetString(0)

                            Console.WriteLine(textReader)
                        End While
                End Using
                sqlite_conn.Close()
            End Using

        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try

        watch.Stop()
        Dim elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds
        Console.WriteLine("Finished Stopwatch: " & elapsedMs & "ms")
    End Sub
```

Comment: Does it hang, or does it just take a long time (how much) to finish?

Comment: Are you sure that this is a problem of the File.ReadAllText ? I would try to turn this code async. Also in what enviroment do you run it ? (This is a mobile app, win app, server app ?)

Comment: @MarkBenningfield It takes 483801 milliseconds to run.

Comment: @NickPolideropoulos I took your advice and moved this code into a backgroundworker. It still takes an abnormally long time to execute. This is on a win app. I need to be able to generate the database via the code on user's machines so that later I can provide updates to it without erasing their user data.

Comment: @DillonConnolly After a bit of research i came up with those two links.
a [Memory-Mapped File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/memory-mapped-files) and a blog with different techniques for loading files [Fasted Way to Read Text Files](http://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/fastest-way-to-read-text-files). Could you try to give it a spin ? Also could you measure the time it takes to load the file and the time it takes to execute the command ? It may be faster to run them in chunks.

Comment: Try splitting the SQL string on the semi-colon, and providing each statement to the command text in a loop. Just a hunch.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Advice from @MarkBenningfield resolved the issue. As he mentioned, split your script on the semi-colon and run each statement separately in a loop. After that everything ran very fast for me.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the .NET SQLite library doesn't run large queries in a single string very quickly, even if you wrap each bulk insert into a transaction; or wrap the entire "ExeecuteNonQuery" method call inside a transaction.

The above solution works, split your large SQL file into individual statements, execute all of them in a transaction and then commit.  I was able to load 15,000 records into a memory based SQLite instance in 0.22 seconds that way.

Cheers.